# FULL OUTER JOIN on multiple keys

Tags: sql, hive

I have two tables (A and B) that I want to merge on 3 fields (department_id, region_id, origin_id).  Each table contains a field for value.  What I'd like to do is combine the two tables and get the difference between the two values.  The issue I'm having is that the composite field combination (department_id, region_id, origin_id do not have nulls) doesn't necessarily exist in both tables.  When I run the following query, I get many more records (~2x) than I expect, so I'm wondering if the query is wrong.  This is in Hive.

```
SELECT
  COALESCE(A.department_id, B.department_id) AS department_id,
  COALESCE(A.region_id, B.region_id) AS region_id,
  COALESCE(A.origin_id, B.origin_id) AS origin_id,
  COALESCE(A.value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT)) - COALESCE(B.value, CAST(0 AS BIGINT)) AS delta_value
FROM
  A FULL OUTER JOIN B
  ON A.department_id = B.department_id
  AND A.region_id = B.region_id
  AND A.origin_id = B.origin_id
```

Comment: How would anyone else know?  No one else knows what you expect.  Sample data and desired results would really help, as would a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Why are you doing a full join on the tables?

Comment: @forpas I'm getting the delta value between the two table, but the segment combination may be missing from either table.  In those cases, I still want the resulting difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are getting *more* records then you expect, that is probably because there are duplicates in one or both tables.  So, run these queries to see where the duplicates are:

```
select department_id, region_id, origin_id, count(*)
from a
group by department_id, region_id, origin_id
having count(*) >= 2;

select department_id, region_id, origin_id, count(*)
from b
group by department_id, region_id, origin_id
having count(*) >= 2;
```

Any `join` will generate a Cartesian product for each combination of key values, if both tables have duplicates.

Comment: The source tables didn't have duplicates, but your answer pointed me to validate that I had "more" records by running the same type of count + having on the resulting data set.  Turns out that I had NULLs in one of my columns in my real data set (100+ fields so it was harder to produce a sample set for my original question).